# Speed Up Label Text change in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, tcp, nsstring

- My program works

  1. send byte using CocoaAsyncSocket (TCP)
  2. get response (byte data)
  3. change byte array to valid data (int / nsstring / etc)
  4. change label text with it(step 3)

I put a NSLog and watched. Log shows almost fast and my function (change label text) runs well. However, I can see change label`s text on simulator about 4~5 second later then function called.

My first way is this

- get a byte array - split into nsdata - change to nsstring - input array - get string - add sub string (like '000%' or '000 sec') - change label text

And Second is

- get a byte array - split - change to nsstring - call a function (add sub string - change label text)

Well... How can I boost its change speed?

Comment: I've noticed in the past that when I have an NSTimer running as fast as possible or a while loop (which is usually a million times faster)... if I ADD a NSLog the script slows down a ton! Try commenting out your NSLog and visually checking the speed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the label text should happen "almost instantly", and when it takes this long it is usually caused by not updating the label text on the main thread.  It is a UIKit object, therefore it must only be modified on the main thread.

Use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.label.text = myString;
});
```

Comment: WOW!!! GOOOOOD! It works well. Because of your answer, I know the importance of it. Thanks again

Comment: Great, glad to hear that! Many other strange things can happen if you don't follow this rule, and they can be very tricky to track down...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when fetching events from the Calendar with almost an identical delay. If what Inafziger suggested doesn't work for you, I suggest using `performSelectorOnMainThread:` and call a method to update your labels in your "Step 3."

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourMethodToUpdateLabels) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

It worked great for my situation. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: This will do the same thing, but using the block is a little easier to follow and understand while reading through the code.

Comment: I figured as much. I'm not at your skill level, and didn't understand your code! Just trying to contribute though. Understanding blocks is a goal of mine.

Comment: No worries, and another option is always good.  I just wanted you to know too!  In this case, it is really pretty simple.  You can put any code that you want in between lines 1 and 3 and it will simply run on the main thread during the next iteration of the run loop.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for the extra info :)